# Android: GoogleAuthIOException for drive api

Tags: android

I want save my folder into google drive through google drive api.

First i went  to google console  get clientId by generate sha-1key
Used on this project

And I also have firebase project linked into project.

I got GoogleAuthIOException.

My code here

```
 try {
                        //CODE TO CHECK FOLDER AVAILABILITY IN GOOGLE DRIVE
                        do {
                            FileList result = service.files().list()
                                    .setQ("mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'")
                                    .setSpaces("drive")
                                    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                                    .setQ("trashed = false")
                                    .execute();
                            for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file : result.getFiles()) {
                                fnam = file.getName().toString();
                                allFiles.add(fnam);
                                if (fnam.equals("com.package.name")) {
                                    favail = true;
                                    foldid = file.getId();
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
                                    edit.putString("GoogleDrive", "" + file.getId());
                                    edit.commit();
                                    break;
                                }
                                System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n",
                                        file.getName(), file.getId());
                            }
                            pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
                        } while (pageToken != null);

                        // IF NOT ANY FOLDER NAMED IS NOT FOUND THEN THIS CODE WILL CREATE A NEW FOLDER.
                        if (!favail) {
                            com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
                            fileMetadata.setName("foloername");
                            fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
                            if (foldid.equals("")) {
                                com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata)
                                        .setFields("id")
                                        .execute();

                                foldid = file.getId();
                                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
                                edit.putString("GoogleDrive", "" + file.getId());
                                edit.commit();
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
            ///////////////I got execption 
             here//////////////////////////////////
                        Log.d("driver",e.toString());
                    }
```

### Log for error trace

09-10 16:13:28.685 22974-25682/Packackagename  D/driver:

com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException

Comment: Could you share entire error log?

Comment: Please share the Log, you can add e.printStackTrace() in catch block to get the logs.

Comment: I upate my log trace